# How to pass a list of a picklist component via AJAX to my Java controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Project: jsp + AngularJS

I have a modal, where I already pass some info to my Java controller via POST (ajax), it works fine.

But, I inserted a new component and I do not know how to receive my selected list of the picklist component, check image to understand:

[image]

For example, I have there fields I pass via POST to my java controller and works fine:

```
$scope.cadastraCertificado = function() {       

$http.post('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado/salvaCertificado', {
    urlCertificado :     $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.urlCertificado,
    dataValidadeCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.dataValidadeCertificado.toString(),
    senhaCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.senhaCertificado
    //picklist????????          
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.sucesso();
}, function(response) {         
});

};
```

But I do not know how to receive data from my list selected in the picklist component, the ones from the right side.

How can I do that?

My picklist:

```
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">                                          
                                        <select ng-model="corvo" multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" name="my_multi_select1[]">
                                            <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}" ng-click="atribuirUm($index, c)">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>
                                            <option selected ng-repeat="c2 in clientes2" value="{{c2.idCliente}}" ng-click="limparUm($index, c2)">{{c2.razaoSocial}}</option>
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>                                          
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how my js looks like after working ok:

```
BoxApp.controller("CadastroCertificadoController", function($scope, $http) {

$scope.clientes = {};
$scope.listaEmpresas = [];

$scope.iniciar = function() {
    $http.get('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado').success(function(response) {
        $scope.clientes = response;
    });
};

$scope.iniciar();

/**
 * Trabalhando o componente picklist
 */
$scope.clientes2 = [];      
$scope.atribuirUm = function(index, c) {
    var cliente = {};
    cliente.idCliente = c.idCliente;
    cliente.razaoSocial = c.razaoSocial;
    $scope.clientes2.push(cliente);
    $scope.clientes.splice(index, 1);
}
$scope.limparUm = function(index, c2) {
    $scope.clientes2.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.clientes.push(c2);       
}

/**
 * Trecho para validar o form ao submeter.
 */
$scope.submitted = false;
$scope.submitForm = function(form, clientes2) {     
    $scope.listaEmpresas = $scope.clientes2;
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (form.$valid) {          
        $scope.cadastraCertificado();
    }
};  

/**
 * Requisição POST (ajax)
 */
$scope.cadastraCertificado = function() {

    var dados = {
            urlCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.urlCertificado,
            strDataValidadeCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.strDataValidadeCertificado.toString(),
            senhaCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.senhaCertificado,
            listaEmpresas : $scope.listaEmpresas                
    };

    $http.post('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado/salvarCertificado', dados).then(function(response) {

    }, function(response) { 
        $scope.sucesso();
    });
};  

$scope.sucesso = function() {
    $scope.closeMyPopup();
    $scope.iniciar();       
};  

$scope.closeMyPopup = function() {
    $(myModal_autocomplete).modal('hide');
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.corvo` will contain an array with the IDs (the `value`s) of the selected elements, so you can just send that array:

```
$http.post('/boxmlV2/cadastrocertificado/salvaCertificado', {
    urlCertificado :     $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.urlCertificado,
    dataValidadeCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.dataValidadeCertificado.toString(),
    senhaCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.senhaCertificado,
    corvo: $scope.corvo         
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.sucesso();
}, function(response) {         
});
```

I assume you are sending JSON data, otherwise you have to serialize it to a string, for example using `$scope.corvo.join(',')`.

Comment: Jeroen, tks for reply. I tried, look, the array comes empty. 

http://imgur.com/TMuKxSf

Comment: Aah.. now I see you have a second select box where you move the items to, I don't see that in your code... can you include that in your question?

Comment: Jeroen, I just have 1 select, I was confused too but this is how this component was built in bootstrap, there is a .js from bootstrap that creates the second picklist.
Therefore, if you see, inside my select there is 2 options tag, 1 defines left and the other the right.